# Parameter tags value '' violated a constraint (Expected argument of type \"array or Traversable\", \"string\" given)"

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, nelmioapidocbundle

please i need your help, i'm trying to insert an image using nelmio bundle but it gives me this error Parameter tags value '' violated a constraint (Expected argument of type \"array or Traversable\", \"string\" given)"

my controller is as follows

```
     /**
 * @ApiDoc(description="Uploads photo with tags.")
 *
 * @Rest\FileParam(name="image", image=true, description="Image to upload.")
 * @Rest\RequestParam(name="tags", requirements=".+", nullable=false, map=true, description="Tags that associates photo.")
 * @Rest\View()
 */
public function postPhotoAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher, array $tags)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $photo = new Photo();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PhotoType, $photo);

    if ($tags) {
        $tags = $em->getRepository('TestTaskTagsBundle:Tag')->findOrCreateByTitles($tags);
    }

    $form->submit($paramFetcher->all());

    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        return $form->getErrors();
    }

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $photo->addTag($tag);
    }

    $em->persist($photo);
    $em->flush();

    return array('photo' => $photo);
}
```

how to solve that please

Comment: sure that $tags really is an array? how does your findOrCreateByTitles function look like?

Comment: tags is an array , in entity class     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PhotoTag", mappedBy="photo", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection|PhotoTag[]
     */
    private $photoTags;

Comment: findOrCreateByTitles function is an other thing

Comment: No, your action is called with $tags - I am pretty sure you aren't getting an array here.

Comment: yes this is the problem, how to insert an array in sandbox nelmio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error come from your own requirements, you are requiring `nullable=false` and `map=true` but you don't pass any value (i.e. `value "" violated a constraint`).

Set the `nullable` attribute to false in your `RequestParam`:

```
* @Rest\RequestParam(name="tags", requirements=".+", nullable=true, map=true, description="Tags that associates photo.")
```

Or assign values to your `tags` parameter.

PS: The problem is about FOSRestBundle, not nelmio/api-doc-bundle that is here **only** for document your api.

**EDIT**

To insert an array in nelmio sandbox, use this as key value:

```
Key: tags[] , Value: 'tag1'
```

And do this for each tag you want to pass (a new key-value pair).

Comment: how to assign an array ? this is my problem

Comment: it works now, thank you, an other question please , how to pass file in url ?

Comment: See the `@FileParam` annotation, look at [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/param_fetcher_listener.html).
Please don't forget to accept my answer as it solved your problem.

Comment: Ah, on the top-left corner of it, you can see the down/up voting arrows, just below you should have a green check, click it and it will be the better thanks that you can give :)